# Differences between Oracle platform versions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to monitor Oracle database using SQL queries from internal tables. Are there any differences between Oracle for UNIX/Windows/Linux/OS?

In particular, do these tables exist and have the same structure in every platform? Do they change between 10g and 11g?

- `V$SYSSTAT`
- `V$SESSTAT`
- `v$session`

I don't have access to test environments of production systems to check the tables differences.

Comment: If suppose you aren't asking if they're just selling the same binaries year after year. What does "SQL queries from internal tables" mean exactly?

Comment: For example are these tables always the same in every platform: `V$SYSSTAT, V$SESSTAT, v$session`?

Comment: Why this question is downvoted? I need this information.

Comment: It wasn't me but the hover text on the vote down button is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"; it's rather unrelated to how much you need it because the feature is intended to keep the quality of the site.

Comment: Well, as I said. I don't have access to these platforms.

Comment: Still, you have to understand that this is not a paid support service that exists to serve you (and even in paid support services you're always asked for detailed information anyway). As you might have noticed, I've merged your follow-up information into the question itself. Now it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, internal system views for the same Oracle version are the same on different platforms.
System views might be different between Oracle releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the information in Oracle documentation. It's hard to find anything there but since it's published on-line you can use Google or any other search engine and search for "Oracle 10g V$SYSSTAT", "Oracle 11g V$SYSSTAT", etc.

For instance, [docs for V$SYSSTATon 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2150.htm#REFRN30272) show the table exists and gives a list of column names, types and other relevant details. It doesn't mention that this information depends on the OS so we can assume it's universal.